# I am not sure if my JSON is properly formatted to access it

Tags: php, javascript, json

Here is another *JSON* question (I always struggle with arrays).

My PHP code returns the following *JSON* structure:

```
[{"breed":{"msg":"Breed is required","placement":"#breed_error_1","return":"false"}},{"breed":{"msg":"Breed does not exist","placement":"#breed_error_2","return":"true"}}]
```

My PHP code is:

```
$breed[]["breed"] = array("msg"=>"Breed is required","placement"=>"#breed_error_1", "return"=>"false");
$breed[]["breed"] = array("msg"=>"Breed does not exist","placement"=>"#breed_error_2", "return"=>"true");
```

And the AJAX code:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    cache: false,
    url: "validate_breed",
    data: element+"="+$(elementSelector).val()+"&v="+validateElement,
    context: document.body,
    dataType: 'html',
    success: function(data){
        alert(data);

    }
});
```

`alert(data)` alerts out the *JSON* structure for debugging purposes.

How do I access the breed section of *JSON* object and all of the following index/keys?

Comment: if your php is outputing JSON then you can specify in `$.ajax` where `dataType: 'json'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the JSON reformatted:

```
[
   {
      "breed":{
         "msg":"Breed is required",
         "placement":"#breed_error_1",
         "return":"false"
      }
   },
   {
      "breed":{
         "msg":"Breed does not exist",
         "placement":"#breed_error_2",
         "return":"true"
      }
   }
]
```

What you have is an array `[]` of two objects `{}`.

To start with you'd do a `for (var i = 0; i < JSON.length; i++)` loop to get each object (of which you have 2).

Snippet:

```
for (var i = 0, len = JSON.length; i < len; i++){
    thisBreed = JSON[i].breed; //now this == {"msg" : etc etc}
    for (prop in thisBreed) {
        console.log(thisBreed.msg + thisBreed.placement + thisBreed.return);
    }
}
```

Comment: In order for me to get this to work successfully I needed to do:  
var myObject = eval('(' + data + ')');  Apparently I needed to use eval for all examples given by everyone answering my question. The data type is set to JSON so, Why is eval still required?
  
-Rich

Comment: Because what comes over the wire is still just a string of text. It might happen to look like JSON or XML or whatever, but until some sort of parser goes through it (like eval() for javascript) it won't mean anything. Sorry to have left this out. jQuery ajax can be set to do it automagically, fwiw.

Comment: No worries Alex.  I fully understand this now :-)

Comment: @dottedquad on the php side before you echo out the output to ajax, did you `json_encode` your output array?

Comment: Yes I did.  My encode code is: $this->breed_return = json_encode($breed);

Answer (score 2):

A `for(item in data)` loop should do the trick, there are other articles around that talk about getting the values

actually
[How do I loop through or enumerate a JavaScript object?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/684672/248903)

Comment: +1 Accepted answer on linked Q is how I would go (and have gone) about it in my own work.

Answer (score 1):

Use `console.info` in FireFox and you'll be able to visualize the object.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way ensure proper json is to bulid the array in php tw way you want it then use http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php on the array befor you send it back

Comment: `function breed_check($str)  
  {  
   $breed = array();  
     
   if($str == NULL)  
   {  
    $breed[0]["breed"] = array("msg"=>"Breed is required","placement"=>"#breed_error_1", "return"=>"false");  
    $breed[1]["breed"] = array("msg"=>"Breed does not exist","placement"=>"#breed_error_2", "return"=>"true");  
   }  
   $this->breed_return = json_encode($breed);
  }`    
I did form the array then did json_encode.  Code snippet is included

Answer (score 1):

Here is the [JSFiddle Demo:](http://jsfiddle.net/bG5D7/)

For instance if this is your output JSON object, then you can access index of each breed using a for loop:

```
var myJSON = [{
    "breed": {
        "msg": "Breed is required",
        "placement": "#breed_error_1",
        "return": "false"
    }},
{
    "breed": {
        "msg": "Breed does not exist",
        "placement": "#breed_error_2",
        "return": "true"
    }}];

for(var i=0;i<myJSON.length; i++){
     console.log(myJSON[i].breed);
}
```

This would console output two objects under each of the two breed

Comment: I created a new .js file and .html file to test out your example.  I understand how this works now; however, when I implement this example into my project I receive the following error in firebug:  myJSON[i].breed is undefined  
  
http://pastebin.com/KhG6K7V9

Comment: @dottedquad can you post what `console.log(myJSON)` gives you?

Comment: The code works when I implemented var myObject = eval('(' + data + ')'); As Alex Mcp explained, "Until some sort of parser goes through it (like eval() for javascript) it won't mean anything."

Answer (score 0):

Try This one

```
for (var i = 0, len = JSON.length; i < len; i++){
  console.log(JSON[i].breed.msg +" - "+ JSON[i].breed.placement +" - "+ JSON[i].breed.return);
}
```